# Can Ink Treader Nephilim's Electrolyze copies target players?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander, mtg-multiplayer

I am curious if the [Electrolyze](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Electrolyze) copies created by targeting [Ink-Treader Nephilim](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ink-Treader%20Nephilim) can be aimed at players for 1 point of damage or if all the damage must go to the creatures that Inky specifies the copies must target.

I have reason to believe no based on the wording of cards like [Wild Ricochet](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Wild%20Ricochet), where it specifies on WR that you can pick new targets.

This sort of question also applies to cards like [Liquid Fire](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Liquid%20Fire) and [Arc Lightning](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Arc%20Lightning).

Answer (score 6):

No, you cannot, because the card specifically states that each copy targets "one of those creatures." So the target for the copy is specified in the rules of the card itself, there is no option to choose a different target.

Arc Lightning is the same, but Liquid Fire works a little differently. With liquid fire, there is only one target, the creature. How much damage is done to the creature vs the creature's controller is chosen as you cast the original Liquid Fire, and that same chosen number will be applied to the copies. (By rule Rule 706.10). So if you chose "x = 0", thus dealing 0 damage to  Ink-Treader Nephilim, and 5 to  Ink-Treader Nephilim's controller, then 0 damage will be dealt to each creature, and 5 to each creature's controller. (So players who control multiple creatures will take 5 damage for each creature they control, not just 5 damage total).

Comment: Indeed not mechanically, but flavourfully you can with Form of the Squirrel.